# How is body language linked with meditation success?

Tags: meditation-body

Body language (smiling) seems to be linked to meditation success as per Bhante Vimalaramsi:

> smiling is an important aspect for the meditation. Learning to smile with mind and raising slightly the corners of the mouth helps mind to be observant, alert and agile.
>
> [Source](http://library.dhammasukha.org/simple-easy-to-understand-mindfulness.html)

What are the mechanics behind this or how it works?

---

In addition these talks through not related to make suggestion that there is a link between body language, smiling and our well being:

- [Your body language shapes who you are](http://www.ted.com/talks/amy_cuddy_your_body_language_shapes_who_you_are)
- [The hidden power of smiling](http://www.ted.com/talks/ron_gutman_the_hidden_power_of_smiling)

Comment: It does not need to be any body who study under Bhante Vimalaramsi. If you can successfully formulate a explanation to a more neutral psychology view on the matter we can get to how it works according to Buddhism (http://www.ted.com/talks/amy_cuddy_your_body_language_shapes_who_you_are).

Comment: interesting. i hear this sort of thing from a lot of secular meditation teachers. not just with smiling, but also with straight back, open chest, etc.

Comment: in my observation these techniques seem to counter frustration, negative states of mind, etc.

Comment: Do you have any material I can go through?

Answer (score 4):

Thich Nhat Hahn is the only one I have read who attributes a significance to smiling. It may have to do with the challenging times he has had to endure.

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/marianne-schnall/beliefs-buddhism-exclusiv_b_577541.html

The interview with him contains much of his practice, but here is an excerpt about smiling

> We humans have lost the wisdom of genuinely resting and relaxing. We
>   worry too much. We don't allow our bodies to heal, and we don't allow
>   our minds and hearts to heal. Meditation can help us embrace our
>   worries, our fear, our anger; and that is very healing. We let our own
>   natural capacity of healing do the work.
>
> Total relaxation is the secret to enjoying sitting meditation. I sit
>   with my spine upright, but not rigid; and I relax all the muscles in
>   my body. Breathing in, I bring my attention to one part of my body;
>   breathing out, I smile with gratitude and love to that part of my
>   body. For example, I breathe in and I bring my attention to my face.
>   On my face there are about 300 muscles, and whenever I get worried,
>   angry or sad, these 300 muscles harden, and anyone who looks at me can
>   see that I'm tense. But if while breathing in I can be aware of my
>   face, and breathing out I can smile to my face, then that tension
>   immediately dissipates. It's almost like a miracle. In just a few
>   breaths we can feel peace, happiness, and relaxation on our face. Our
>   face becomes light, fresh, like the kind of flower it was before.
>   Every face is a flower.
>
> After breathing three or four times with "breathing in I am aware of
>   my face; breathing out I smile to my face," then I can breathe in and
>   bring my awareness to the muscles in my shoulders, because our
>   shoulder muscles are often tense. As I breathe out, I relax and smile
>   with my shoulders. Gradually we can move through the whole body, so
>   after just a few minutes we can already normalize our body so it feels
>   light and relaxed.
>
> This is something everyone can do in the first minutes of sitting, and
>   not only when we are in the meditation hall. Wherever we sit, we can
>   sit beautifully, just like we are doing sitting meditation, and we
>   will feel stability and freedom. Sitting down to eat or do paperwork,
>   we sit upright and relaxed. Let us sit like the Buddha.

Answer (score 3):

A person who is advanced towards realization of emptiness will typically display a calm, peaceful, and blissful demeanor, even during trying circumstances. I would say that smiling is a natural part of such a demeanor.